# How to connect ftp to local ipv6 address

Tags: linux, ftp, metasploit

I am trying to connect to a ftp server in my network. I only have the link local ipv6 address (fe80::1:1:ff:f). When I try to connect via filezilla I get the error "Connection attempt failed with "EINVAL - Invalid argument passed".

Using the command line ftp tool I just get the "invalid argument" error.

I know that it is possible to connect to the ftp server because I used metasploit's auxiliary/scanner/ftp/ftp_login tool with my credentials and it successfully connected.

I tried Filezilla, ftp, lftp, metasploit tools.

```bsh
ftp -6 [fe80::1:1:ff:f]
```

I expect to connect to the ftp server.

[Here's a link to a screenshot of a successfull metasploit login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRmsG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link-local addresses in many operating systems require the interface to be explicitly specified, e.g. `fe80::1:1:ff:f%eth0` on Linux. This is because all links share the same fe80::/64 prefix.

(Windows is an exception because it supports discovering the correct interface through NDP probing.)

Note that if you use FTP passive mode, it's still possible that you won't be able to establish *data* connections, because the client might not know that it needs to remember interface used for the control connection and copy it to all addresses used for data connections.